# Множественная загрузка файлов

Tags: php, javascript

Видел в одном сайте загрузку файла.  Есть javascript ссылка. При клике создаётся новое окно с нужными размерами. Там форма загрузки файла и кнопка "добавить". В этой форме нет js, но когда нажимаешь "добавить", она полностью закачивает файл, обновляет страницу и сама закрывается. А на главной странице добавляется "тег" с её адресом.

JS-ссылка на главной странице

```
function multi_call4505() {
  window.open("forum_serv.php?q=6","attach","toolbar=0,width=400,height=120");
}
```

В новом окне обычная форма с инпут-файлом

```
<form method="Post" action="forum_serv.php?q=7" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Интересует 2 вопроса, как главная страница узнаёт о загрузке файла и как дочернее окно без JS само-закрывается?

Comment: Может там всё-таки есть javascript? Откуда такая уверенность?

Comment: вот. нет js, думаю всем этим занимается главная страница  
http://forum.hiasm.com/forum_serv.php?q=6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а, всё, понял почему закрывается
он переключает страницу на forum_serv.php?q=7  в которой js
    <script>window.opener.req_serv("forum_serv.php?q=8");window.close();<;/script>
потом сразу же переключает на forum_serv.php?q=8 и закрывает окно
но как главная страница об этом узнаёт ?

Comment: разобрался, метод opener ломится к родителю